# Using blob images with a "fancybox" plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I`m trying to display blob images from my db with a fancybox plugin (fancybox.net) like this:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($vinyl['f_pic']); ?>" data-fancybox-group="4"><img src="img/eyey.png"></a>
```

But that doesn't work. When i press on my eyey.png i get just blob data (in text) in my fancybox window.

Can you even do that ? Display images in blob format in a fancybox window ?

Comment: Okay, i think i got it. All i needed to do, was to add type : 'image' as a parameter in my fancybox func, like so: $(".fancybox").fancybox({type : 'image'}); ... Seems like fancybox did not recognized the data he received.. I guess this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to link the fancy box to a page and put the code to display the image on that page.   I don't think you can use href=data: in a fancybox.